Flutter _TypeError (type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<CustomerList>')
 try { response = await postMethod( uri: url, body: body, mobileNo: custMobileNo, ); } catch (e) { response = null; } if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) { try { return CustomerResponse.fromJson( convert.jsonDecode(response.data)["data"][0]); } catch (e) { CustomerResponse(custList: response.data); } } else { CustomerResponse(custList: response.data); }
My Response File.
factory CustomerResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
CustomerResponse(
message: json["message"],
status: json["status"],
code: json["code"],
custList: json["data"] == null
? []
: List.from(
json["data"].map((x) => CustomerList.fromJson(x))).toList(),
);
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
"message": message,
"status": status,
"code": code,
"data": custList == null
? []
: List.from(
custList.map((x) => x.toJson()).toList(),
),
};
[![Response](https://i.sstatic.net/dML3n.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/dML3n.png)
i want to send data to server.
and show success  messages . to user

Your code is mess, you did not added Customer Response class, you did not told use the error or prblm you are facing, please add these details

You should create a CustomerList object and add them to custList. There is a sample:
    ...
    if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        return CustomerResponse.fromJson(
            convert.jsonDecode(response.data)["data"][0]);
      } catch (e) {
        List<CustomerList> customerList = [];
        //data or customerData what name you give
        for (var item in convert.jsonDecode(response.data)["data"]) {
          customerList.add(CustomerList.fromJson(item));
        }
        CustomerResponse(custList: customerList);
        ...
      }
    }
    ...

